# Is there way to make an array modifier match another object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, instances

Im trying to array a light fixture so that it shows up on the column of this wall. The wall has an array modifier, is there a way to set up the array modifier for the light fixture so that it shows up in the same location on each column? Ive done this before with lights and a plane but I cant remember how.[image]

Comment: Do you need the light fixture to be a separate object? Because if not you can select the wall and the light and use CMD+J you can combine them into one object so the array modifier works on it.

Comment: @NascentSpace the light fixture needs to be a separate object because it will throw off the normals

Comment: @PeterRandall Being a part of the same mesh can change normals (which can also be fixed with custom normals) but just being part of the same object, barring unusual circumstances, will not change normals.  You can have multiple, separate meshes inside a single mesh object.

Answer (score 1):

As Nascent Space and Nathan have already mentioned - unless you have custom normals/separate set of modifiers for the fixture and the wall, you can simply join these meshes into the same object (CTRL+J). It's the easiest way which should work out of the box.

If you have to keep two separate objects, it's still feasible, although hacky.

You can add another Array Modifier to the fixture and sync its Count with the wall's Array Modifier's Count:

- RMB on the source (wall) Array Count > Copy as New Driver
- RMB on the dest (fixture) Array Count > Paste Driver

You'll still have to set the appropriate Constant Offset along Y for the fixture. I believe you don't want to calculate the value manually, but rather have it filled in automatically, based on your walls dimension. You can use another driver for this:

- RMB on the fixture's Array Constant Offset Distance Y > Add Driver
- set the **Type** to `Scripted Expression`
- change Input Variable type to `Single Property` and name it (eg. `offset`)
- set the **Prop** to your Wall Object and the **Path** to `dimensions.y` (as long as your wall is duplicated along the Y axis)
- turn on **Use Self** in the expression and set it to `offset / self.count`

[image: driver]

It's also good to parent your fixture to the wall so that it follows the transforms, but again - this is a hacky approach which has its negative implications. I'd strongly recommend joining both meshes into a single object.